# Texturing issue with extruded parts

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, extrude

I am making a mug where I generated the handle with extrusion (ctrl + E). While everything looks fine in solid display, the handle looks weird in Material preview display once I apply the texture. Please see below screenshot. The edges between each faces are so obvious and the faces are just alternating with very similar colors, which is so artificial.

[image]

I attached all the .blend and texture files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gn7SL3unDlbgAjpGWleE2wZ9O6pNGUXu?usp=sharing

Not sure if the modeling is wrong in the first place or I need to do a different UV mapping, or anything else? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: weird, it looks like it has to do with the unwrap and the normal map? maybe first try to unwrap this part again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your blend file I see you have a lot of duplicated geometry, Merge by Distance removes 2240 verts.  You also have a lot of faces with the Normals facing the wrong way -- in Edit mode click the Show Overlays drop-down and check the Face Orientation box to see them easily, then select some of the red faces and Mesh > Normals > Flip, continue until all outside faces show blue.

[image]

After that you probably do want to check your UV map, the islands are not well-positioned over the image.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized that there are lots of duplicated faces. Good to know that! It looks the issue on the handle is because I removed the inner surface (surface facing the mug) to make it hollow. As a result, the texture looks strange.